# Script to compress contents of a folder once per month into an archive and then delete

Tags: batch-file, 7zip, winrar

I need a script to backup the contents of a directory including sub folders to a single archive file. I would like to run this script on a monthly schedule (will use task scheduler), so every 30 days the script compress the contents of the folder and create a NEW archive file with the month as the name of the file and then delete the files/subfolders.

Ive put together a mixture of coding I found online, this is the product. The code functions as desired, just not sure if the logic is there.

```
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x

IF %month%==1 (
SET mth=Jan
)    
IF %month%==2 (
SET mth=Feb
)    
IF %month%==3 (
SET mth=Mar
)
IF %month%==4 (
SET mth=Apr
)    
IF %month%==5 (
SET mth=May
)   
IF %month%==6 (
SET mth=Jun
)   
IF %month%==7 (
SET mth=Jul
)    
IF %month%==8 (
SET mth=Aug
)    
IF %month%==9 (
SET mth=Sep
)    
IF %month%==10 (
SET mth=Oct
)    
IF %month%==11 (
SET mth=Nov
)    
IF %month%==12 (
SET mth=Dec
)

for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%mth%-%Year%.zip" "%%X\"    

IF EXIST %mth%-%Year%.zip (
    FOR /D %%p IN ("*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
) ELSE (
    echo NO
)
```

If anyone could help me optimize this code or improve it I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What code exactly do you use? And What have you tried so far to match your desired result?

Comment: i suggest you reread the thread and check out the command line options of 7z (2nd solution in the accepted answer) to compress multiple files into a single archive, the scheduling can be done with windows task scheduler. also this is not the type of question that should be asked on SO since you dont have any code and are just asking for general advice

Comment: @SBH - the code would either have to be VB, powershell or some form of windows Batch.. i havent found anything that suits my needs yet. everything i have found so far is close but not what i need.

Comment: Sorry, but SO doesn't work that way. Please show us what you have tried so far, and what *specific* problem you need help with.

Comment: the code ive been trying to work with is                                        
`for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"`

 the issue is the above code creates a seperate zip file for each sub-folder within the directory. i need it to only create 1 zip file with all the sub-folders contained inside.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use one of the two solutions below and run either **WinRAR** or the batch file using **7-Zip** with task scheduler on last day of a month some minutes before midnight, or every 30 days if it is not really necessary to have all files of a month in one archive.

One note before reading below about the solutions:

Do not create the ZIP archive in the folder with the files and subfolders to archive. That would not be a good idea on using the solution with **7-Zip**.

---

### WinRAR solution

My first solution for this task is using **WinRAR** which makes this task a one-liner:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" m -afzip -agMMM-YYYY -ibck -cfg- -ep1 -m5 -r "C:\Path to Destination Folder of Archive\.zip" "C:\Temp\Folder with Files and Subfolders to compress\"
```

The destination folder of the ZIP archive must already exist on execution of **WinRAR**.

In program files folder of **WinRAR** there is the text file **Rar.txt** which contains all commands and switches with an explanation for console version *Rar.exe*. Help of **WinRAR** has on tab *Contents* the item **Command line mode** with subitems **Commands** and **Switches**. Both can be used to create a command line like above.

The command **m** is explained with moves files and directories which results in the files and directories being erased upon successful completion of the packing operation.

The switch **-afzip** is a **WinRAR** only switch which selects ZIP as archive format. *Rar.exe* does not support this switch as the console version supports only creating RAR archives.

The switch **-ag** with option **MMM-YYYY** results in appending to name of archive file before file extension the month in short name format and the year, e.g. **Nov-2014**.

The switch **-ibck** results in minimizing **WinRAR** window to Windows system tray on archive processing.

The switch **-cfg-** results in ignoring configuration file and RAR environment variable (just for safety).

The switch **-ep1** results in excluding from archive the entire path to base directory which results here not putting "C:\Temp\Folder with Files and Subfolders to compress\" into the archive, just the file and subfolders in this folder.

The switch **-m5** sets best compression for the archive.

The switch **-r** is a very important one as it tells **WinRAR** to recursive compress all files and folders.

The archive file created is for example **Nov-2014.zip** because the name of the archive file is just **.zip**.

Investing a small amount of money for **WinRAR** license can make many archiving and backup tasks very simple.

Of course it would be also possible to create a RAR archive instead of a ZIP archive.

---

### 7-Zip solution

The **7-Zip** solution needs more effort as currently not having features like **WinRAR** for such backup tasks.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list') do (
    set "Value=%%x"
    if "!Value:~0,5!"=="Month" (
        set "Month=!Value:~6!"
    ) else if "!Value:~0,4!"=="Year" (
        set "Year=!Value:~5!"
    )
)
if "%Month%"=="1"  set "Month=Jan" & goto Compress
if "%Month%"=="2"  set "Month=Feb" & goto Compress
if "%Month%"=="3"  set "Month=Mar" & goto Compress
if "%Month%"=="4"  set "Month=Apr" & goto Compress
if "%Month%"=="5"  set "Month=May" & goto Compress
if "%Month%"=="6"  set "Month=Jun" & goto Compress
if "%Month%"=="7"  set "Month=Jul" & goto Compress
if "%Month%"=="8"  set "Month=Aug" & goto Compress
if "%Month%"=="9"  set "Month=Sep" & goto Compress
if "%Month%"=="10" set "Month=Oct" & goto Compress
if "%Month%"=="11" set "Month=Nov" & goto Compress
set "Month=Dec"

:Compress
set "FolderToCompress=C:\Temp\Folder with Files and Subfolders to compress"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx=9 -r -tzip "C:\Path to Destination Folder of Archive\%Month%-%Year%.zip" "%FolderToCompress%\*"
rd /S /Q "%FolderToCompress%"
md "%FolderToCompress%"
endlocal
```

First, the commands **FOR**, **IF** and **SET** are used to process output of [Windows Management Instrumentation Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) to get month and year.

For help on those 3 commands run in a command prompt window (console window)

- `help for` or `for /?`
- `help if` or `if /?`
- `help set` or `set /?`

Or the Microsoft TechNet articles for [for](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx), [if](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920.aspx) and [set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490998.aspx) are read for details.

And help on the other commands **GOTO**, **MD**, **RD** and **SETLOCAL** can be get the same way.

After determining month and year for archive file name, **7-Zip** is executed to create a ZIP file in a destination folder which of course must already exist.

And also **7-Zip** has a help which on *Contents* tab has the item **Command Line Version** with the subitems **Commands** and **Switches**.

The command **a** is for compressing files into an archive. There is no **m** as **WinRAR** offers. So deletion after compression must be done separately.

The switch **-m** with the option **x=9** sets best compression.

The switch **-r** is a very important one as it tells **7-Zip** to recursive compress all files and folders.

And the switch **-tzip** selects the standard **ZIP** format.

With the command **RD** the folder "C:\Temp\Folder with Files and Subfolders to compress\" with all files and subfolders is deleted and next with **MD** the folder itself is recreated as I suppose the folder itself should remain for next month.